# Calculating the Difference in values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
index   Rod_1   label
0   [[1.94559799] [1.94498416] [1.94618273] ... [1.8941952 ] [1.89461277] [1.89435902]] F0
1   [[1.94129488] [1.94268905] [1.94327065] ... [1.93593512] [1.93689935] [1.93802091]] F0
2   [[1.94034818] [1.93996006] [1.93940095] ... [1.92700882] [1.92514855] [1.92449449]] F0
3   [[1.95784532] [1.96333782] [1.96036528] ... [1.94958261] [1.95199495] [1.95308231]] F2
```

Each cell in the Rod_1 column has an array of 12 million values. I'm trying the calculate the difference between every two values in this array to remove seasonality. That way my model will perform better, potentially.

This is the code that I've written:

```
interval = 1    
for j in range(0, len(df_all['Rod_1'])):
      for i in range(1, len(df_all['Rod_1'][0])):
        df_all['Rod_1'][j][i - interval] = df_all['Rod_1'][j][i] - df_all['Rod_1'][j][i - interval]
```

I have 45 rows, and as I said each cell has 12 million values, so it takes 20 min to for my laptop to calculate this. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So for Rod_1 index 0 there are 12 million elements in the array? when you say you want to calculate the difference between every two values will it be like if the values were [1,2,3,4], is your output going to be [1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4]? This is O(N^2) right?

Comment: or do you want your output to be [1,2,3,4] --> [1-2, 2-3, 3-4]?

Comment: Every value minus the value before. Its going to be (t) - (t-1).
So: [2-1, 3-2, 4-3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be much faster, I've tested up till 1M elements per cell for 10 rows which took 1.5 seconds to calculate the diffs (but a lot longer to make the test table)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

#Create test data
np.random.seed(1)
num_rows = 10
rod1_array_lens = 5 #I tried with this at 1000000
possible_labels = ['F0','F1']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rod_1':[[[np.random.randint(10)] for _ in range(rod1_array_lens)] for _ in range(num_rows)],
    'label':np.random.choice(possible_labels, num_rows)
})

#flatten Rod_1 from [[1],[2],[3]] --> [1,2,3]
#then use np.roll to make the diffs, throwing away the last element since it rolls over
start = time.time() #starting timing now
df['flat_Rod_1'] = df['Rod_1'].apply(lambda v: np.array([z for x in v for z in x]))
df['diffs'] = df['flat_Rod_1'].apply(lambda v: (np.roll(v,-1)-v)[:-1])
print('Took',time.time()-start,'to calculate diff')
```

[image]

Comment: This does work very fast, around 1 min. However, is there any way that you can do this without flattening the Rod_1? My other functions rely on it being that way. So, this messes up all of my other functions.

Comment: unfortunately the speedup is because the Rod_1 is flattened and turned into a numpy array. there may be other ways to speedup that I don't know. is it ok for your to keep a flattened and unflattened Rod_1 column like the example above? then your other functions could still use the unflattened

Comment: Not really, I guess I have to change my other functions. Thanks.